# php search on string comma separated and get element that match

Tags: php, regex, match, cpu-word

I have a question, if anyone can help me to solve this.  I have a string separated by commas, and I want to find an item that partially matches:

```
$search = "PrintOrder";
$string = "IDperson, Inscription, GenomaPrintOrder, GenomaPrintView";
```

I need to get only the full string from partial match as a result of filter:

```
$result = "GenomaPrintOrder";
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with `preg_match` ?

Comment: If you know how the aggregate string has been glued together, you can use that glue to explode that string into an array and loop over it.

Comment: `$matches = array_filter(explode(',', $string), function ($value) use ($search) { return strpos($value, $search) !== false; });`

Comment: You might want to consider upvoting good answers even if you didn't accept them, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `preg_match_all` you can do like this.

**Php Code**

```
<?php
  $subject = "IDperson, Inscription, GenomaPrintOrder, GenomaPrintView, NewPrintOrder";
  $pattern = '/\b([^,]*PrintOrder[^,]*)\b/';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  foreach ($matches as $val) {
      echo "Matched: " . $val[1]. "\n";
  }
?>
```

**Output**

```
Matched: GenomaPrintOrder
Matched: NewPrintOrder
```

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/RwymhA)**

Comment: get this error: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 25

Comment: @WalterNuñez: I have edited the code. Please check. In the latest example I have added an extra string `NewPrintOrder` to demo multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
$search = "PrintOrder";
$string = "IDperson, Inscription, GenomaPrintOrder, GenomaPrintView";
$result = array();
$tmp = explode(",", $string);
foreach($tmp as $entrie){
    if(strpos($entrie, $string) !== false)
        $result[] = trim($entrie);
}
```

This will get you an array with all strings that match your search-string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to get the result:

```php
$search = "PrintOrder";
$string = "IDperson, Inscription, GenomaPrintOrder, GenomaPrintView";

$regex = '/([^,]*' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '[^,]*)/';

preg_match($regex, $string, $match);

$result = trim($match[1]); // $result == 'GenomaPrintOrder'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$search = "PrintOrder";
$string = "IDperson, Inscription, GenomaPrintOrder, GenomaPrintView";


$array = explode(" ", $string);
echo array_filter($array, function($var) use ($search) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many different answers already, here is another:

```
$result = preg_grep("/$search/", explode(", ", $string));
print_r($result);
```